# want to load xml url and get the element value from them using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, xmldom

I have one XML Url:

http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=22.3000&lng=70.7833&radius1000

I want to load this url and get `<asciiName>` element value.
Store it into different variable.
Using `javascript` if possible.

Comment: if it is a cross domain request,I think you are tin trouble, else you can use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX)

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes i am try to use Ajax any idea...

Comment: what is the domain of your page

Comment: hey i think you not getting my question exactly i have one html file i write in  them some code with this url and want to get from this url element value